# Why unable to verify local issuer certificate? (https calls for google)

Tags: macos, ssl, docker, certificate, alpine-linux

I am using docker desktop to run a simple node:16-alpine through mac. Which I added a ca-certificates, curl and openssl.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main ca-certificates curl openssl
```

No matter what I do, I just can't make https calls inside of my container, a simple `curl https://google.com` will return `unable to get local issuer certificate`, both inside of the container or in the build process.

Here is the log from a openssl call, `openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443`:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net), emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = "Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t) "
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = www.google.com
   i:C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = "Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t) "
 1 s:C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = "Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t) "
   i:C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net), emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
 2 s:C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net), emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
   i:C = US, ST = California, L = San Jose, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Root CA, emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = www.google.com

issuer=C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = "Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t) "

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4123 bytes and written 745 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Comment: Did you install the third-party TLS certificate within your container? Google doesn’t use Zscaler Cloud Security to sign their TLS certificates

Comment: No I didn't, @Ramhound ,  all I did was installing the ca-certificates, and I believe docker desktop loads my ca-certificates from the mac host.. should I install it? how can I manage to do it?

Comment: Should be similarly to how you loaded it on your other machines.  I assume your using the cloud security through a proxy, vpn, or physical hardware?

Comment: Humm I believe it is used by vpn, because it came already setup for me by the company I work for.

Comment: Somebody had to trust that third-party certificate, otherwise, you would get TLS errors regardless if you were connected to the VPN or not

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound you pointed me in the right direction, the problem really was that we are using zscaler as an inteceptor, and inside the container there wasnt their ca certificate to validate, if you want to answer, i would accept.